# Ant Design render all the components of tabs when changing a tab and at the first rendering

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using And Design for my project in the development and I ran into something weird.

1. It renders all the components of tabs at the first rendering. As you can see below the console of the snippet, like 'children 1 children 2 children 3'
2. It renders all the components of tabs when switching tabs as well. You can see the same console log like the previous case.

Am I doing something wrong?

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/card-type-tab-antd-4-24-3-forked-2vkrhm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```js
// demo.js
const App = () => {
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <Tabs
      onChange={(key) => {
        setTab(key);
      }}
      type="card"
      accessKey={tab}
      items={new Array(3).fill(null).map((_, i) => {
        const id = String(i + 1);
        return {
          label: `Tab ${id}`,
          key: id,
          children: (
            <div>
              {console.log(`children ${id}`)}
              <span>-----------------{id}</span>
            </div>
          )
        };
      })}
    />
  );
};
```

```
// console
children 1 
children 2 
children 3
```

I think it should trigger rendering the content of the tab once when changing a tab or at the first rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is being recreated on every render of `App`. `App` gets rendered every time `setTab` is called with a different value. If you don't want that to happen, you can declare the array outside the component, or use `useMemo`.

```
const items = new Array(3).fill(null).map((_, i) => {
  const id = String(i + 1);
  return {
    label: `Tab ${id}`,
    key: id,
    children: (
      <div>
        {console.log(`children ${id}`)}
        <span>-----------------{id}</span>
      </div>
    )
  };
})

const App = () => {
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <Tabs
      onChange={(key) => {
        setTab(key);
      }}
      type="card"
      accessKey={tab}
      items={items}
    />
  );
};
```

OR

```
const App = () => {
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(1);

  const items = useMemo(
    () =>
      new Array(3).fill(null).map((_, i) => {
        const id = String(i + 1);
        return {
          label: `Tab ${id}`,
          key: id,
          children: (
            <div>
              {console.log(`children ${id}`)}
              <span>-----------------{id}</span>
            </div>
          ),
        };
      }),
    [] // empty dependency array means never run again
  );

  return (
    <Tabs
      onChange={(key) => {
        setTab(key);
      }}
      type="card"
      accessKey={tab}
      items={items}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it ok to trigger all the content of tabs(in children property) at the first rendering?

Comment: sure, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I thought each content of the tabs should be rendered only when the tab is selected.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "rendered", the element won't exist in the DOM until the tab is selected if that's what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean the element just will be created? not be appended? or react just keep render output?

Comment: JSX elements exist as JavaScript objects before they are injected into the DOM. https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects. You control what gets rendered in the browser by returning a different object. You create the objects and the tab component can return the correct object based on the selected tab.

Comment: Yeah, you're are right. I was confused. Thank you for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Try `destroyInactiveTabPane` prop on Tabs.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <Tabs
      onChange={(key) => {
        setTab(key);
      }}
      type="card"
      accessKey={tab}
      items={items}
      destroyInactiveTabPane={true} // add this prop
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: thnx dude you save my day